# How to transmit german umlauts to an index created by splitidx?

Tags: indexing, subdividing, german

I'm currently trying to transmit German umlauts in index entries (e.g., `\sindex[p]{Böll, Heinrich}`) to the index created by [`splitidx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/splitindex). Right now, to sort the entries the right way, the umlauts are redefined by `\def Ä{"A}` etc. (see below).

But now - which commands to tell TeXnicCenter to print the umlauts correctly after sorting them? At the moment entries appear as `Boll, Heinrich` and not as `Böll, Heinrich`. Are anyone able to support a motivated, but still incompetent LaTeX user?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
%...

\usepackage[ngerman]{betababel}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}

\shorthandon{"}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \def Ä{"A}%
  \def Ö{"O}%
  \def Ü{"U}%
  \def ä{"a}%
  \def ö{"o}%
  \def ü{"u}%
  \def ß{"s}%
    \def \~n{"n}%
}
\shorthandoff{"} 

\usepackage[makeindex,split,idxcommands]{splitidx}
\newindex[Personenverzeichnis]{p}
\newindex[Sachregister]{s}

\frontmatter
%...
\mainmatter

Der Schriftsteller Heinrich Böll\sindex[p]{Böll, Heinrich} gilt zu unrecht als der \ldots

\appendix 
\printindex*
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can indent your code by 4 spaces to format it. Or use the code icon.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: This is **not** in issue of **both** `splitindex` and TeXnicCenter, but of `makeindex`! Although: Which version of TeXnicCenter do you use?

Comment: There is no need for such an redefinition.

Answer (score 5):

I cannot see it with the `utf8` encoding:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[makeindex]{splitidx}
\newindex[Personenverzeichnis]{p}
\newindex[Sachregister]{s}

\begin{document}
Der\sindex[p]{Äro, Willi} Schriftsteller Heinrich Böll\sindex[p]{Böll, Heinrich} 
gilt\sindex[p]{Boa, Heinz} zu unrecht als der \ldots
\sindex[p]{Boll, Willi}\sindex[s]{Æro, Heinrich}\sindex[s]{Aro, Will}\sindex[s]{Äro, Ernst}
\appendix 

\printsubindex*

\end{document}
```

[image]

I run

```
pdflatex <file>
splitindex <file>
pdflatex  <file>
```

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't seem to work with `polyglossia` under `xelatex`, though. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps not exactly the answer, but it would solve your issue. You can use the built-in ability of makeindex to have a sorting entry and a display entry, in that form:

```
\sindex[p]{boll heinrich@Böll, Heinrich}
```

where `boll heinrich` will be used for sorting, and `Böll, Heinrich` for printing. This way, you can add formating too if you want :

```
\sindex[p]{boll heinrich@\textsc{Böll, Heinrich}}
```

for instance. And I think you would'nt need to redefine the Umlauts anymore.